# How to define environmental variables in a solution of Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, environment-variables, solution

I have a VS2015 solution with several projects.
I want to know if there is a way to define some solution level variables  to be used in the after build event of all contained projects.

I have searched the web and the only answers i can find involve the use of os level variables which i don't like because i want to be able to share my .sln file with other developers and it should work by simply changing a few values instead of creating a new set of variables every time with risks of typos and other errors.

Thank you

Comment: But if you have to change the values you are defeating somehow the purpose of your approach. If you accompany your solution with a script to create/update the environment variables (PowerShell is specially good for that purpose) you would decouple the solution. Also, It would actually allow you to have different scripts for different CI phases/users.